# Why do relatively many South Africans hold an unfavorable view of India?

Tags: india, public-opinion, polling, south-africa

> In contrast, South Africans see India more critically than favorably.
> About half say they have an unfavorable view of the country –
> including 36% who hold a very unfavorable view, while 28% report a
> favorable opinion. About half in the Netherlands and Spain also say
> they have a critical opinion of the country.

https://www.pewresearch.org/global/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2023/08/PG_2023.08.29_views-of-india_report.pdf

Why do relatively many South Africans hold an unfavorable view of India? There are more South Africans who view India unfavorably than South Africans who view the country favorably (51% versus 28%). Why is there such a big difference in view?

This is especially striking since in European countries the view tend to be balanced or leaning towards a positive view of the country. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing what these surveys actually measure, i.e. what the questions are. Pew says this info is on their website but I can't find it. If you asked me if I had a favourable or unfavourable view of most countries I'd say "It's complicated."

Comment: This question (and a couple similar questions) [are being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/what-should-we-do-with-all-those-why-do-country-people-view-country-favorab).